# Autoscaling using Ceilometer/Aodh failed to trigger an alarm in the openstack rocky

Tags: openstack, ceilometer

[Here](https://docs.openstack.org/senlin/rocky/scenarios/autoscaling_ceilometer.html) is the document I refer to

1.sample_server.yaml

```
type: os.nova.server
version: 1.0
properties:
  name: cirros_server
  flavor: m1.small
  image: b86fb462-c5c2-4a08-9fe4-c9f86d05763d
  networks:
    - network: external-net
```

2.Execute the following command line

```
# openstack cluster create --profile pserver --desired-capacity 2 mycluster
# openstack cluster receiver create --type webhook --cluster mycluster --action CLUSTER_SCALE_OUT --params count=2 r_01
# export ALRM_URL01='http://vip:8777/v1/webhooks/aac3433a-40de-4d7d-830c-e0035f2a4d13/trigger?V=1&count=2'
# aodh alarm create --type gnocchi_resources_threshold --aggregation-method mean --name cpu-high --metric cpu_util --threshold 70 --comparison-operator gt --granularity 300 --evaluation-periods 1 --alarm-action $ALRM_URL01 --repeat-actions False --query metadata.user_metadata.cluster_id=$MYCLUSTER_ID --resource-type instance --resource-id f7e0e8a6-51a3-422d-b631-7ddaf65b3dfb
```

3.log into each cluster nodes and run some CPU burning workloads there to drive the CPU utilization high

I added log output to /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/aodh/notifier/rest.py when trigger the alert request

```
class RestAlarmNotifier(notifier.AlarmNotifier):
    def notify(self, action, alarm_id, alarm_name, severity, previous,
           current, reason, reason_data, headers=None):
    body = {'alarm_name': alarm_name, 'alarm_id': alarm_id,
            'severity': severity, 'previous': previous,
            'current': current, 'reason': reason,
            'reason_data': reason_data}
    headers['content-type'] = 'application/json'
    kwargs = {'data': json.dumps(body),
              'headers': headers}
    max_retries = self.conf.rest_notifier_max_retries
    session = requests.Session()
    LOG.info('#########################')
    LOG.info(session)
    LOG.info(kwargs)
    LOG.info(action.geturl())
    LOG.info('#########################')
    session.mount(action.geturl(),
                  requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=max_retries))
    resp = session.post(action.geturl(), **kwargs)
    LOG.info('$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$')
    LOG.info(resp.content)
    LOG.info('$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$')
```

Some error messages are output in the /var/log/aodh/notifier.log log, as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3egLD.png)

The reason is the error caused by adding the body request parameter, the direct post request can be successful, for example, using curl request without the body parameter

```
curl -g -i -X POST 'http://vip:8777/v1/webhooks/34e91386-7176-4b30-bc17-5c3503712696/trigger?V=1'
```

Aodh related version packages are as follows：

```
python2-aodhclient-1.1.1-1.el7.noarch
openstack-aodh-api-7.0.0-1.el7.noarch
openstack-aodh-common-7.0.0-1.el7.noarch
openstack-aodh-listener-7.0.0-1.el7.noarch
python-aodh-7.0.0-1.el7.noarch
openstack-aodh-notifier-7.0.0-1.el7.noarch
openstack-aodh-evaluator-7.0.0-1.el7.noarch
openstack-aodh-expirer-7.0.0-1.el7.noarch
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved. [Here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/senlin/+bug/1801755) is the document I refer to

1. Modify aodh rest.py(aodh/notifier/rest.py)
   https://github.com/openstack/aodh/blob/master/aodh/notifier/rest.py#L79
   Under the headers['content-type'] , add this line: headers['openstack-api-version'] = 'clustering 1.10'
2. Restart aodh service